# Ionic 3 Error: Failed to transpile program

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic3

I have an old ionic 3 project but when I try to build the project I get the following error

[13:45:55]  typescript: node_modules/@types/ncp/index.d.ts, line: 29
Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'PathLike'.
L29:source: string,
L30:destination: string,

My current ionic version is:
Ionic CLI          : 6.16.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
NodeJS             : v15.4.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.4.0/bin/node)
npm                : 7.18.1

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and re-building your app